# Power law distribution for galaxy populations

Tags: galaxy-cluster, galactic-halo

I've learned that observed galaxy populations exhibit single power-law clusterings within several tens of megaparsecs in comoving scale.

I'm trying to sample some astronomical data from this project: [Illustris simulations](https://www.tng-project.org/), and I'm beginning with star (baryonic) data from galaxy subhalo scale.

1. Do cosmological objects exhibit a different distribution at this smaller, sub-halo, kilo-parsec, resolution scale?
2. If so, **how large should my sample be so I can observe this power law distribution**, using the dataset from Illustris? Should I use dark matter halos, instead of baryonic sub-halos?